# Looping through two lists, replacing values if found

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have two lists that I will need to loop through. One is a list of values I would like to get rid of from the other list (REPLACE_LIST), and the other list is just the data.

```
REPLACE_LIST = ['\'','[','[','\\','\"',',','〈','(',')','♬','➡',
'!','…','｡','！','〉','？','～','?','《','》','≪','≫','',']','\\n']

t=['♬(ｵｰﾌﾟﾆﾝｸﾞﾃｰﾏ)\n', '〈頃は 昔々➡\n']
```

I've tried things like

```
for char in REPLACE_LIST:
    for i in t:
        if char in i:
            i = i.replace(char, ' ')#I want to get rid of the characters
```

But that does not work.

How can I better do this?

To clarify, I would like "t" to look like:

```
['ｵｰﾌﾟﾆﾝｸﾞﾃｰﾏ', '頃は 昔々']
```

Comment: You need to actually put the modified string back in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set back the string into the list, so you'd better iterate over the indices and use `values[i]`, also don't need to check inclusion you can simplify by removing it as `replace` will just do nothing if the pattern is not present

```
values = ['♬(ｵｰﾌﾟﾆﾝｸﾞﾃｰﾏ)\n', '〈頃は 昔々➡\n']
for i in range(len(values)):
    for char in REPLACE_LIST:
        values[i] = values[i].replace(char, '')
```

You can use `re` also by creating a pattern that does an `OR` on all elements

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("|".join(REPLACE_LIST))
for i in range(len(values)):
    values[i] = pattern.sub("", values[i])
```